# In a pandas dataframe, how can I fill in missing values with a list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'animals': [None, 'cat', 'dog', None, 'hippo', 'elephant']})
```

The column animals has two None values.

I want to replace the first missing value with one value and the second missing value with another value.

The code I have so far replaces only for the first missing value. The second missing value is not updated.

```
new_df = df.animals.fillna(pd.Series(['unknown1', 'unknown2'])
new_df

0    unknown1
1         cat
2         dog
3         NaN
4       hippo
5    elephant
Name: animals, dtype: object
```

I expected that value for index 3 to be equal to unknown2.

How can I get this to work so that I can replace the missing values in a given column with a pandas series of missing values with a length equal to the number of missing values in that column?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with a Series of same length:

```
s = pd.Series(['unknown1', 'unknown2'])
df['animals'] = df['animals'].fillna(df['animals'].isna().cumsum().sub(1).map(s))
df

    animals
0  unknown1
1       cat
2       dog
3  unknown2
4     hippo
5  elephant
```

---

**How this works**
The issue with your current approach is that `fillna` either works with a single fill value or else a Series of same length as the column/DataFrame being filled. It will then take the Nth fill value from the series to fill the NaN at the Nth position in the column. From the docs:

> `value : scalar, dict, Series, or DataFrame`
> Value to use to fill holes (e.g. 0), alternately a
> dict/Series/DataFrame of values **specifying which value to use for
> each index** (for a Series) or column (for a DataFrame).

So we get around this by creating a temp series with similar value that has the fill value we want at the right position:

```
df['animals'].isna().cumsum()

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
Name: animals, dtype: int64

s = pd.Series(['unknown1', 'unknown2'])
df['animals'].isna().cumsum().sub(1).map(s)

0    unknown1
1    unknown1
2    unknown1
3    unknown2
4    unknown2
5    unknown2
Name: animals, dtype: object
```

Comment: Great solution, thank you. The details as to why this works is really helpfull

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get this to work so that I can replace the missing values in a given column with a pandas series of **missing values with a length equal to the number of missing values in that column**?

You can simply use `loc` and don't use `pd.Series` to avoid index alignment issue:

```
df.loc[df['animals'].isna(), 'animals'] = ['unknown1', 'unknown2']
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    animals
0  unknown1
1       cat
2       dog
3  unknown2
4     hippo
5  elephant
```

Your code can only work if you use the same index for your `Series`:

```
>>> df['animals'].fillna(pd.Series(['unknown1', 'unknown2'], 
                                   index=df[df['animals'].isna()].index))

0    unknown1
1         cat
2         dog
3    unknown2
4       hippo
5    elephant
Name: animals, dtype: object
```